# JQUERY : Confusion to find next element in a complex structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have big confusion while getting next element in a complex structure.

**Complex structure :**

```
<p>before data</p>

<div>
   <p>some data <span id="getnext"></span></p>
</div>    

<div>
    <p>some data <span><ins>inserted</ins></span></p>
</div>    

<div>
   <div>
      <p>some data <span><del>deleted</del></span></p>
   </div>
</div>   

<div>
   <div>
       <ol>
             <li>Some changes made<span data-change="get">in this place</span></li>
       </ol>    
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the complex structure I have on my machine.

I want to get all next element which has `ins`,`del`,`span[data-change="get"]`

For now, I'm in id `"getnext"`.

And I try the following way to do that.

```
var arr_ = $('#getnext').next('ins,del,span[data-change="get"]');
```

But, this is not working very well.What am I do now?

Any ideas or suggestions, please.

**Maximum structure variant:**

```
<p>some data <span id="getnext"></span>extra data<ins>some data</ins></p>

<p>deleted<span><del>some data</del></span> data</p>

<ol>
  <li><ins>list insert</li>

  <ul>
     <li><del>deleted</del></li> 
  </ul>

</ol>

<div>
  <p><span data-change="get">changed data</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#getnext')` has no siblings. Use `$('#getnext').parent().next('div ins, div del, div span[...]')`

Comment: Ok, but the structure changes every time.I only have `$('#getnext')` as a stable id.Then what am I going to do?

Comment: @Rajesh `$('#getnext').parent()` also doesn't have any siblings.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I meant `div`. You can try `$('#getNext').closest('div').next(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need go to the `closest` (parent) **div** first

```
$('#getnext').closest( "div" );
```

Then check for those `next` `div` element which **has** child `ins`, `del` etc

```
$('#getnext').closest( "div" ).nextAll( "div:has(ins,del,span[data-change='get'])" );
```

or

```
$('#getnext').closest( "p" ).nextAll( "p").has("ins,del,span[data-change='get']" ) ;
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = $('#getnext').closest("div").nextAll("div:has(ins,del,span[data-change='get'])");
console.log(output.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>before data</p>

<div>
  <p>some data <span id="getnext"></span></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>some data <span><ins>inserted</ins></span></p>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <p>some data <span><del>deleted</del></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>Some changes made<span data-change="get">in this place</span></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but the structure changes every time.I only have `$('#getnext')` as a stable id.Then what am I going to do?

Comment: In that case not sure how I  can help unless you can tell me the range in which your structure will vary in.

Comment: kk, I will put the maximum structure variant.

Comment: @MariSelvan Also try the code I have shared with different variants of your structure.

Comment: Ok,I will try it.Thank you